# Using Lebesgue density to show $A-A$ contains a non-trivial interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable set with positive measure. The claim that $A-A$ has non-trivial interval is just the Steinhaus Theorem, and I understand the [more elementary proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem). However, I've been made aware that the Lebesgue density theorem could also be used, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the first part of exercise 7.5 from Rudin's *RCA* which asks you to prove that if $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(A), m(B)>0$, then $A+B$ contains an interval (just take $B=-A$ to get your case). Rudin provides a very good outline there, so if you only need a hint where to begin, check it out first. Anyway, filling in the details of that outline we have: since the measure of the sets is positive, we can find $a_0 \in A$ and $b_0 \in B$ s.t. $a_0, b_0$ have Lebesgue density 1. Hence, there is $R>0$, s.t. for any $0<\rho<R$, $m(B\cap (b_0-\rho,b_0+\rho))>\frac{9}{10}m((b_0-\rho,b_0+\rho))=\frac{18}{10}\rho$. Put $c_0=a_0+b_0$ and for $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, $\delta>0$ define $I_{\epsilon,\delta}=(a_0+\epsilon-\delta,a_0+\epsilon+\delta)$, $B_{\epsilon,\delta}=\{c_0+\epsilon-b: b\in B, |b-b_0|<\delta\}$. First of all, note that if $|b-b_0|<\delta$ then $a_0+\epsilon-\delta<c_0+\epsilon-b<a_0+\epsilon+\delta$, so $B_{\epsilon,\delta}\subset I_{\epsilon,\delta}$. Also, $-B_{\epsilon,\delta}=\{-(c_0+\epsilon) +b: b\in B, |b-b_0|<\delta\}=-(c_0+\epsilon)+B\cap (b_0-\delta,b_0+\delta)$. Therefore, for $\delta<R$: $m(B_{\epsilon,\delta})=m(-B_{\epsilon,\delta})=m(B\cap (b_0-\delta,b_0+\delta))>\frac{18}{10}\delta$, hence $m(I_{\epsilon,\delta}-B_{\epsilon,\delta})<2\delta - \frac{18}{10}\delta=\frac{\delta}{5}$. Since $a_0$ is a density point, there is $0<r<R$ s.t. $m(A\cap (a_0-r,a_0+r))>\frac{1}{2}m((a_0-r,a_0+r))=r$. Pick any $\epsilon$ with $0<|\epsilon|<\frac{r}{4}$ and let $\delta=r-|\epsilon|$. Now, $a_0+\epsilon-\delta \ge a_0-|\epsilon|-\delta=a_0-r$ and $a_0+\epsilon+\delta \le a_0+|\epsilon|+\delta=a_0+r$, thus $I_{\epsilon,\delta}\subset (a_0-r,a_0+r)$ and $m((a_0-r,a_0+r)-I_{\epsilon,\delta})=2r-2\delta=2|\epsilon|$. We have $2|\epsilon|+m(A\cap I_{\epsilon,\delta})\ge m(A\cap ((a_0-r,a_0+r)-I_{\epsilon,\delta}))+m(A\cap I_{\epsilon,\delta})=m(A\cap (a_0-r,a_0+r))>r$ $m(A\cap I_{\epsilon,\delta})>r-2|\epsilon|>\frac{r}{2}$. Similarily, since $\delta<R$, we have $\frac{\delta}{5}+m(A\cap B_{\epsilon,\delta})>m(I_{\epsilon,\delta}- B_{\epsilon,\delta})+m(A\cap B_{\epsilon,\delta})\ge m(A\cap I_{\epsilon,\delta})>\frac{r}{2}$, so $m(A\cap B_{\epsilon,\delta})>\frac{r}{2}-\frac{\delta}{5}=\frac{r}{2}-\frac{r}{5}+\frac{|\epsilon|}{5}=\frac{3r+2|\epsilon|}{10}>0$. This shows that $A\cap B_{\epsilon,\delta}$ isn't empty. Let $x\in A\cap B_{\epsilon,\delta}$, then there is $b\in B$ s.t. $x=c_0+\epsilon-b\in A$, hence $c_0+\epsilon \in A+B$. Since it's true for any $\epsilon \in (-\frac{r}{4},\frac{r}{4})$, we conclude $(c_0-\frac{r}{4},c_0+\frac{r}{4})\subset A+B$.